# Selecting a sequence of random length starting and ending with specific values and limited by another column

Tags: r

I have a fairly large data set that has the form of the following table:

```
   value ID
1      0  A
2      0  A
3      1  A
4      1  A
5      0  A
6     -1  A
7      0  B
8      1  B
9      1  B
10     0  B
11     0  B
12     0  B
13     1  C
14     1  C
15     0  C
16     1  C
17     1  C
18     1  C
19     0  C
```

Essentially I'd like to transform  the above, keeping only the first and last values of  sequences that start with an occurrence of zero followed by a unknown number of ones and end at the last occurrence of one:

```
   value ID
2      0  A
4      1  A
7      0  B
9      1  B
15     0  C
18     1  C
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
dput of the first example follows:

```
structure(list(value = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("-1", 
"0", "1"), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label =  c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you mean within each value of `ID` you want the first row where `value=0` and the last row where `value=1`? Why choose row 2 rather than row 1 for the first row of your output table?

Comment: I want to keep value=0 only if it is followed by a value=1, not first value=0

Comment: Wouldn't the output be of the form `data.frame(value=rep(0:1, length(unique(df$ID))), ID=rep(unique(df$ID), each=2))` for any input data frame of the form you specified? Or is it that the specific row numbers matter? Or are there some values of `ID` that don't have a starting zero or ending 1?

Comment: @eipi10 `rep(0:1, length(unique(df$ID)))` can be replaced by just `0:1`. Other than that, it could be that a certain `ID` would have multiple sequences of `01+`  patterns. Try doing `df[11:12, 1] <- 1` and then see if your predefined structure works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt using `data.table` and `stringi` packages combination

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(.I[stri_locate_all_regex(paste(value, collapse = ""), "01+")[[1]]], 0:1), by = ID]
#    ID V1 V2
# 1:  A  2  0
# 2:  A  4  1
# 3:  B  7  0
# 4:  B  9  1
# 5:  C 15  0
# 6:  C 18  1
```

This basically converts each group to a single string and then detects the beginning and the end of parts that match the `01+` regex while subsetting from the row index `.I`. Eventually I'm just adding `0:1` to the data (which seems redundant to me at least).